# GeoServer features in layers are not displayed in GML when requested by their FeatureID

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

My GeoServer WFS service behaves strangely:

```
http://myserverurl.de/geoserver/my:layer/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Ahaus_neu:Graeber&maxFeatures=50&
```

I get 50 features, as I expect, and the features are tagged like this:

```
<gml:featureMember>
  <my:layer fid="myfeature.1">
    ...
  </my:layer>
 </gml:featureMember>
....
<gml:featureMember>
  <my:layer fid="myfeature.50">
    ...
  </my:layer>
 </gml:featureMember>
```

Usually, I could retrieve single Feature myfeature.XY like this

```
http://myserverurl.de/geoserver/my:layer/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Ahaus_neu:Graeber&featureID=myfeature.XY&
```

This works with featureID=myfeature.1, featureID=myfeature.2, and, weirdly, featureID=myfeature.387

It does NOT work with any other featureID, even though they are displayed in the main request.

For featureID=myfeature.3, for example, I just get:

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xsi:schemaLocation="myurl//WFS-basic.xsd">
   <gml:boundedBy>
     <gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
   </gml:boundedBy>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

There is nothing that featureID myfeature.1, myfeature.2, and myfeature.387 have in common except that. This behaviour correlates with the ability of any property of the feature to be updated from OpenLayers. (Which works only for myfeature.1, myfeature.2 and myfeature.387).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your data stored in a database without a primary key?

Answer (score 1):

*The reason for this trouble was discovered by @iant and it was that GeoServer can generate stable fids only if the the database table has a primary key.

My original answer below can hopefully serve as an example about how to use online demo services for debugging.*

Have a try with complete fid as you get it with GetFeature like &FeatureID=myfeature.3?

This works:

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&featureID=states.1

But this does not find anything:

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&featureID=1

Also using a workspace tied URL works with this server

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/topp/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&featureID=states.7

Comment: sorry, my question was incomplete. I edited it.

Comment: Do you have the demo layers left in your GeoServer? Does FeatureID work with your topp:states when you access it through /geoserver/wfs?